# Is singing non-muslim songs kufr and shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, music, singing

Since very young age if you have been singing non-muslim songs and it has become habit so you can't stop singing songs.  Sometimes songs are about other  religions so it may include shirk and kufr words.  I like to know is it major sin to sing songs like that? would it put you out of Islam? Please note I am not asking if singing is haram, I am asking would it put you out of Islam.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly is said. Making certain statements does take one out of Islam, the method of saying them is irrelevant.