# Is listening to Music or Songs Shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, music

Considering many Genres of Modern day Music like pop,rock etc. are influenced by Christian Music which is full with Shirk wouldn’t it be Shirk to listen to these Genres because of their influence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is singing non-muslim songs kufr and shirk?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52784/is-singing-non-muslim-songs-kufr-and-shirk)

Answer (score 0):

If it has shirk then yeah don't listen to it because Allah said this in the Quran about shirk  "Allah forgives not that partners should be set up with Him, but He forgives anything else, to whom He pleases, to set up partners with Allah is to devise a sin most heinous indeed" (Quran An-Nisa 4:48)
and you would literally be intrested in it which takes you far from islam.